# Fill subset of rows with values from row above

Tags: r

I have a long format dataset with longitudinal data and for one variable I want to fill in the missings in timepoint 0 with the values in timepoint 1, but I do not want to fill in the missings from timepoint 1 with values from timepoint 2 and so on.
My dataset is ordered by id and timepoint.

I have used the fill function succesfully in cases where I just needed to fill missings from all timepoints from a specific id.

Example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                 timepoint=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3),
                 var1=c(NA,9,8,10, NA, 10, NA, 12, NA, NA, 12, 11, NA, 12, 12, NA))

> df
   id timepoint var1
1   1         0   NA
2   1         1    9
3   1         2    8
4   1         3   10
5   2         0   NA
6   2         1   10
7   2         2   NA
8   2         3   12
9   3         0   NA
10  3         1   NA
11  3         2   12
12  3         3   11
13  4         0   NA
14  4         1   12
15  4         2   12
16  4         3   NA
```

This is what works when I just need to fill any missing no matter the timepoint:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(`var9`:`var12`, .direction = "up") %>%
  as.data.frame
```

But now I have trouble specifying to only fill in the missings in rows at timepoint 0. Any help is appreciated.

My expected output:

```
> df
   id timepoint var1
1   1         0    9
2   1         1    9
3   1         2    8
4   1         3   10
5   2         0   10
6   2         1   10
7   2         2   NA
8   2         3   12
9   3         0   NA
10  3         1   NA
11  3         2   12
12  3         3   11
13  4         0   12
14  4         1   12
15  4         2   12
16  4         3   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `id` and use `replace` to change the values where `timepoint = 0` & `var1` is `NA` from the corresponding value of `var1` where `timepoint = 1` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(var2 = replace(var1, timepoint == 0 & is.na(var1), var1[timepoint == 1]))

#     id timepoint  var1  var2
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1         0    NA     9
# 2     1         1     9     9
# 3     1         2     8     8
# 4     1         3    10    10
# 5     2         0    NA    10
# 6     2         1    10    10
# 7     2         2    NA    NA
# 8     2         3    12    12
# 9     3         0    NA    NA
#10     3         1    NA    NA
#11     3         2    12    12
#12     3         3    11    11
#13     4         0    NA    12
#14     4         1    12    12
#15     4         2    12    12
#16     4         3    NA    NA
```

Comment: This works great for this example. What if I would want to fill the missings in `var1` at `timepoint = 0` with the first (non-missing) value from `timepoint = 1`, `timepoint = 2` or `timepoint = 3`. Would I be able to somehow still use the fill function in upward direction, but only make it fill missings at `timepoint = 0` and NOT any of the other timepoints?

Comment: @RRRRred you could do `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var2 = replace(var1, timepoint == 0 & is.na(var1), 
                    head(na.omit(var1[timepoint == 1]), 1)))` provided you have atleast one value which is not `NA` in each group for that `timepoint`.

Comment: What would you do when all values are NA in some groups. I was thinking of making a separate variable counting NAs in each group, and including an ifelse statement, but that cannot be the easiest solution.

Comment: you can check if the group has all `NA` values and return `NA` maybe ? `if(all(is.na(var1))) NA else replace(var1, time.......`.

Comment: The solution in your first comment throws this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: replacement has length zero.

Comment: @RRRRred If you have new question don't hesitate to ask a new question with reproducible example instead of extending the question in comments. It invalidates the current answers and confuses the people who comes later to this post.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an oversimplification, but you can just call the `fill` function again, but this time with direction down. Then your entire data frame will be complete.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                 timepoint=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3),
                 var1=c(NA,9,8,10, NA, 10, NA, 12, NA, NA, 12, 11, NA, 12, 12, NA))
```

In this case I will use an `ifelse` statement followed the by the `lead` function.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = ifelse(is.na(var1) & timepoint == 0, 
                       lead(var1, 1), var1))
```

Yields:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
      id timepoint  var1
   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1         0     9
 2     1         1     9
 3     1         2     8
 4     1         3    10
 5     2         0    10
 6     2         1    10
 7     2         2    NA
 8     2         3    12
 9     3         0    NA
10     3         1    NA
11     3         2    12
12     3         3    11
13     4         0    12
14     4         1    12
15     4         2    12
16     4         3    NA
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used this exact code for other instances. But in this case, the key thing is that ONLY missings at var1 in rows with `timepoint = 0` are filled in with values from rows with `timepoint = 1`.